# javascript: .style.rotate ="__deg" no me responde en chrome

Tags: javascript, css, dom, google-chrome

estoy intentando rotar un elemento del **DOM** usando la sintaxis mencionada y me funciona perfecto en firefox pero **no en Chrome**. la función la probé y entra bien porque incluso me modifica el valor del atributo posicion que se ejecuta justo despues de rotar el elemento por medio de **css**.

```
    imgFicha = document.getElementById(`${slots[b].elementoDOM.innerHTML.slice(9,18)}`);
    if(slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion === 1){
        imgFicha.style.rotate = "90deg";
        slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion = 2;
    }else if(slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion === 2) {
        imgFicha.style.rotate = "180deg";
        slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion = 3;
    }else if(slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion === 3) {
        imgFicha.style.rotate = "270deg";
        slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion = 4;
    }else if(slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion === 4) {
        imgFicha.style.rotate = "0deg";
        slots[b].fichaColocada.posicion = 1;
    }
}
```

Desde ya les agradezco cualquier ayuda que me brinden y errores que noten en mi código! Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rotate#browser_compatibility) está completamente implementada en pocos navegadores, de forma experimental en otros y algunos pocos todavía no la tienen.

Te sugiero probar con la función [rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) como valor de la propiedad [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform) que tiene [mejor compatibilidad](https://caniuse.com/?search=transform%3Arotate). Ejemplo de uso:

```
imgFicha.style.transform = "rotate(270deg)";
```

El único inconveniente que le veo es que, si quieres aplicar más transformaciones, debes hacerlo en la misma propiedad `transform`, por ejemplo, si quieres rotar un elemento 90º y que se mueva 50px a la derecha:

```
elemento.style.transform = "rotate(90deg) translateX(50px)";
```